# Set webcam grabbing resolution with ImageIO in Python

Tags: python-imageio

Using simple Windows/Python to read from Webcam:

```
camera = iio.get_reader("<video0>")
screenshot = camera.get_data(0)
camera.close()
```

I'm getting a default resolution of 1980x1920. The webcam had different, larger resolutions available. How do I set that UP?

ALSO -
How do I set exposure time? image comes out pretty dark.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the resolution via the [`size` kwarg](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_autosummary/imageio.plugins.ffmpeg.html#parameters-for-reading), e.g. `size=(1280, 720)`

My webcam is my third device and the resolution defaults to `640x360` but has `1280x720` available, so I would do something like:

```py
import imageio.v3 as iio

frame = iio.imread("<video2>", index=0, size=(1280, 720))
```

On a tangent, I'd also suggest switching to the easier `iio.imiter` for stream reading. It tends to produce cleaner code than the old `iio.get_reader` syntax.

```py
import imageio.v3 as iio

for idx, frame in enumerate(iio.imiter("<video0>", size=(1980, 1920))):
    ... # do something with the frame

    if idx == 9:
        # read 10 frames
        break
```

---

Response to your edit:

Setting webcam exposure is a question that actually hasn't come up yet. Webcams typically feature automatic brightness adjustment, but that might take a few frames depending on the webcam's quality.

Manual adjustment might already be possible and I just don't know about it (never looked into it). This is a separate question though and is probably better tracked as a [new issue](https://github.com/imageio/imageio/issues) over at the ImageIO repo.

Comment: Thanks for that, @FirefoxMetzger. Could you please explain the "index=0" bit?

Comment: @Gabe The default index of `imread` for videos (and by extension webcams) is `index=...`, which will read all frames in the video and stack them. (Not super ideal for infinite streams like webcams, but very useful for many other scenarios.) To get a specific frame you have explicitly set `index` to that value, e.g. `index=0` to read the first frame.

Comment: Thanks for that. Two more questions, please: 1. I get an error that I should use imageio_ffmpeg, but that one doesn't have an imread method. 2. Imiter does not seem to produce a matrix or frame. What am I missing?

Comment: @Gabe 1. `imageio_ffmpeg` is an optional dependency that provides a plugin to access FFmpeg. You simply install it and use `iio.imread` as usual. ImageIO will automatically pick up `imageio_ffmpeg` and use it to fulfill the request as needed.  2. Hard to say without seeing the code. In general `iio.imiter` returns a generator that will yield frames, so you'll have to use it inside a `for frame in iio.imiter(...)` statement or do something like `frame = next(frame_generator)` depending on the context.

Comment: I am reading 8MP images from the webcam and each one is taking ages (~5 seconds). Any way to make it go faster?

Comment: @Gabe Other than improving the performance of the library code itself there is nothing that comes to mind.